# How to use GPUImage for Android to get bitmap thumbnails for multiple filters

Tags: android, bitmap, android-gpuimageview

I am new to Android development and I could use some help!

I am trying to create a GridView to display 1 image loaded 9 times with different filters.  I am using the GPUImage framework for Android and the Universal Image Loader.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class FilterActivity extends Activity {

private MyApplication mApp;
private ArrayList<GPUImageFilter>filters;
public ArrayList<Bitmap>bitmaps;
private List<String> filterNames;
int maxWidth = 120;
int maxHeight = 120;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);

    Uri imageURI = mApp.getFirstImagePath();
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    BitmapFactory.Options resizeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    resizeOptions.inSampleSize = 3; // decrease size 3 times
    resizeOptions.inScaled = true;

    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .decodingOptions(resizeOptions)
            .postProcessor(new BitmapProcessor() {
                @Override
                public Bitmap process(Bitmap bmp) {

                    return scaleBitmap(bmp);
                }
            })
            .build();

    Bitmap bmp = imageLoader.loadImageSync(imageURI.toString(), options);

    filterNames = Arrays.asList("grayscale", "documentary", "sepia",
            "posterize", "noFilter", "lomo",
            "cool", "warm", "vignette");

    for (String filterName : filterNames ){
        filters.add(filterWithName(filterName));
    }

    GPUImage mGPUImage = new GPUImage(this);
    mGPUImage.getBitmapForMultipleFilters(bmp,filters, new GPUImage.ResponseListener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void response(Bitmap bitmap) {
            bitmaps.add(bitmap);
        }
    });

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewFX);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });

}

private Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();

    Log.v("Pictures", "Width and height are " + width + "--" + height);

    if (width > height) {
        // landscape
        float ratio = (float) width / maxWidth;
        width = maxWidth;
        height = (int)(height / ratio);
    } else if (height > width) {
        // portrait
        float ratio = (float) height / maxHeight;
        height = maxHeight;
        width = (int)(width / ratio);
    } else {
        // square
        height = maxHeight;
        width = maxWidth;
    }

    Log.v("Pictures", "after scaling Width and height are " + width + "--" + height);

    bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, width, height, true);
    return bm;
}
private GPUImageFilter filterWithName(String name) {

    GPUImageFilter mGPUImageFilter;
    switch (name) {
        default:
        case "noFilter":
            mGPUImageFilter = new GPUImageContrastFilter(.5f);
            break;
        case "grayscale":
            mGPUImageFilter = new GPUImageGrayscaleFilter();
            break;
        case "documentary":
            float[] color = new float[]{1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f};
            mGPUImageFilter = new GPUImageMonochromeFilter(.8f, color);
            break;
        case "sepia":
            mGPUImageFilter = new GPUImageSepiaFilter(.85f);
            break;
        case "posterize":
            mGPUImageFilter = new GPUImagePosterizeFilter();
            break;
        case "lomo":
            mGPUImageFilter = new GPUImagePixelationFilter();
            break;
        case "cool":
            GPUImageLookupFilter amatorka = new GPUImageLookupFilter();
            amatorka.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.lookup_amatorka));
            mGPUImageFilter = amatorka;
            break;
        case "warm":
            mGPUImageFilter = new GPUImageCrosshatchFilter();
            break;
        case "vignette":
            PointF centerPoint = new PointF();
            centerPoint.x = 0.5f;
            centerPoint.y = 0.5f;
            mGPUImageFilter = new GPUImageVignetteFilter(centerPoint, new float[]{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, 0.3f, 0.75f);
            break;
    }

    return mGPUImageFilter;
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return bitmaps.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(position));
        return imageView;
    }


    }
}
```

and the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication.FilterActivity">

android:background="@drawable/background">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutX">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="75dp"
    android:text="@string/effects"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffffff"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:shadowRadius="2"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:id="@+id/roundedLayout">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridViewFX"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="4dip"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="4dip"
        android:padding="4dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I try to compile I get this:

```
    04-07 04:36:12.453    1527-1527/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-07 04:36:12.485    1527-1565/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=22: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c40648)
04-07 04:36:12.485    1527-1565/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 119
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageRenderer$3.run(GPUImageRenderer.java:184)
            at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageRenderer.runAll(GPUImageRenderer.java:126)
            at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageRenderer.onDrawFrame(GPUImageRenderer.java:115)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Any help with pointing out what I am doing wrong and how to fix it will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I tried lot for thumbnails but finally I got only one solution for thumbnails.

`mGPUImage.capture(60,60)` will return you bitmap with applied filter of size 60 x 60 . So you can generate thumbnails by this way and apply you logic for multiple filters thumbnails.

Hope this will work for you.